# Pythonic shortcut for doubly nested for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, nested-loops

Consider if I had a function that took a tuple argument (x,y), where x was in the range(X), and y in the range(Y), the normal way of doing it would be:

```
for x in range(X):
    for y in range(Y):
        function(x,y)
```

is there a way to do

```
for xy in something_like_range(X,Y):
    function(xy)
```

such that xy was a tuple (x,y)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [product from itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> for x,y in product(range(3), range(4)):
...   print (x,y)
... 
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)

... and so on
```

Your code would look like:

```
for x,y in product(range(X), range(Y)):
    function(x,y)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
for xy in product(range(X), range(Y)):
    function(xy)
```

Comment: don't need a comma b/w x and y?

Comment: @yishairasowsky The code works as written. `xy` will be a pair (tuple with two elements) containing one value from `X` and one from `Y` in each iteration. You can unpack the tuple by using `x, y` as the loop variable if you want to. I used `xy` as a single value here because this is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4):

Pythonic they are -> (*modify according to your requirements*)

```
>>> [ (x,y)   for x in range(2)   for y in range(2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

**Generator version** :

```
gen = ( (x,y)   for x in range(2)   for y in range(2) )
>>> for x,y in gen:
...     print x,y
... 
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try product from itertools: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(range(X), range(Y)):
    function(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

def something_like_range(*sizes):
    return product(*[range(size) for size in sizes])
```

for a usage close to what you wanted:

```
for x,y in something_like_range(X,Y):
    your_function(x,y)
```

=)