# How to group multiple lists into single list in a Pythonic way?

Tags: python

I've a function returning list from list of lists where the return list groups members of each list by index numbers. Code and example:

```
def listjoinervar(*lists: list) -> list:
    """returns list of grouped values from each list 
        keyword arguments:
        lists: list of input lists
    """ 
    assert(len(lists) > 0) and (all(len(i) == len(lists[0]) for i in lists))
    joinedlist = [None] * len(lists) * len(lists[0])
    for i in range(0, len(joinedlist), len(lists)):
        for j in range(0, len(lists[0])):
            joinedlist[i//len(lists[0]) + j*len(lists[0])] = lists[i//len(lists[0])][j]
    return joinedlist

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [True, False, False]
listjoinervar(a, b, c)
# ['a', 1, True, 'b', 2, False, 'c', 3, False]
```

Are there ways to make this more Pythonic using itertools, generators, etc? I've looked at examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462047/pythonic-shortcut-for-doubly-nested-for-loops) but in my code there is no interaction b/w the elements of the individual lists. Thanks

Comment: What if the lists are of different lengths? What is your requirement then?

Comment: The assert guards against that and they shouldn't be according to the logic of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a normal situation, I would also use `itertools.chain`, as in Austin's answer.

However, just for completeness, an alternative solution that does not import anything:

```
def join_lists(*a):
    return [element for sub in zip(*a) for element in sub]

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [True, False, False]

join_lists(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
['a', 1, True, 'b', 2, False, 'c', 3, False]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why in a 'normal situation' you'd use itertools.chain when it seems this can be done without it? Are there any other benefits of itertools.chain?

Comment: @shanlodh No, they are effectively the same. However, I personally find `chain.from_iterable(zip(*[a, b, c]))` slightly more readable than the comprehension approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this answer because list comprehensions can be [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632839/transform-list-of-tuples-into-a-flat-list-or-a-matrix) in these cases w/o additional dependencies

Comment: @shanlodh, you might also be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631326/why-is-itertools-chain-faster-than-a-flattening-list-comprehension

Comment: @Austin: thanks, interesting link particularly zwer's comments under the link's OP which mirrors my experience in this case. My OP func seems to be running faster than the more Pythonic solutions in actual code

Answer (score 7):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) + [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import chain

def listjoinervar(*a):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*a)))
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [True, False, False]
>>> listjoinervar(a, b, c)
['a', 1, True, 'b', 2, False, 'c', 3, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and list comprehension:

```
from typing import List, Any

def listjoinervar(*args: List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
    return [item for sublist in list(zip(*args)) for item in sublist]
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [True, False, False]
>>> listjoinervar(a,b,c)
['a', 1, True, 'b', 2, False, 'c', 3, False]
```

The use of type annotations is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without having to import anything, using the `enumerate` and `max` methods:

```
def custom_group(*args):
  biggest, result = max(args, key = lambda x: len(x)), []
  for (i, value) in enumerate(biggest):
    for arr in args:
      if len(arr) > i:
        result.append(arr[i])
  return result
```

You're looping through the biggest list and adding each value from each list at that index (if it exists) to the results list then moving on to the next index until the loop stops.

Using your specified arrays:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [True, False, False]
```

You'd call the function, like this:

```
print(custom_group(a,b,c))
```

Which should result in the following list being outputted:

```
["a", 1, True, "b", 2, False, "c", 3, False]
```

Good luck.

Comment: Please note that those are `lists` and not `arrays`.